# iOS simulator not showing title header

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7

A picture speaks a thousand words so here's what's happening:

[image]

I'm expecting the top bar to hide the table content.

It's a really basic setup. A tab bar controller going to a table view. The contents, however, look like the screenshot. I'm not sure if in previous versions, but in XCode I can't edit the title. Regardless of what the "Top Bar" option on the table view controller is, the same will happen. A title on the view controller has been set, I'm just not seeing how you're supposed to change it. Obligatory XCode screenshot:

[image]

I'm probably missing something silly, or perhaps the simulator is behaving exactly as expected.

Cheers

Comment: I just want to point out that it is simulator not emulator - there is a difference

Answer (score 0):

This is the default behaviour on iOS 7. You can change that by changing the top layout guide's height using the new properties on `UIViewController` such as the `edgesForExtendedLayout` `UIRect` one. For more information about how to work with the iOS 7 UI in view controllers read this document: [iOS 7 UI Transition Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TransitionGuide/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013174)

Comment: Strangely, it was because I wasn't using a navigation controller. The navigation controller will yield a header with a back button, without one it won't.

Comment: A `UINavigationController` does some work for you when combined with a `UITableViewController` or `UICollectionViewController`. Namely, it automatically changes the `contentOffset` of the scrollView (the table or collection view respectively). That's why you don't notice the change when using a navigation controller. If you don't use one, though, you need to set the extended layout's edges.